# Ler e inserir dados numa tabela através de C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho este código para inserir valores numa coluna de uma tabela:

```
        conn.Open();
        comm.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO ArticleBarCode(Code, Code_Article, BarCode, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, IsDeleted)
                           VALUES (@code1, @codearticle, @barcode, 1, @date1, 1, @date1, 0)";
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code1", next);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codearticle", code);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", numbercode);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", DateTime.Now);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

Mas antes de inserir, preciso de ler essa coluna e ver se já existe algum igual. Se não existir, quero inserir, se já existir, NÃO quero inserir de novo, quero seguir em frente.
Alguém sabe como me ajudar nisso ? Urgente !

Comment: Por que você não coloca uma `constraint` de `unique` no banco ao invés de validar na mão?

Comment: Urgente? Urgente?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver alterando seu SQL deixando seu código da seguinte maneira:

```
    conn.Open();
    comm.CommandText = @"
    IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ArticleBarCode WHERE Code = @code1))
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO ArticleBarCode(
          Code, 
          Code_Article, 
          BarCode, 
          CreatedBy, 
          CreatedOn, 
          ModifiedBy, 
          ModifiedOn, 
          IsDeleted
       ) VALUES (
          @code1, 
          @codearticle, 
          @barcode, 
          1, 
          @date1, 
          1, 
          @date1, 
          0
       )
    END";
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code1", next);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codearticle", code);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", numbercode);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", DateTime.Now);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

Espero ter ajudado.